# How can I pass a variable into jQuery timeout

Tags: jquery

I'm seriously struggling today.

I need to pass a variable, or even better an object, into a timeOut as such (example) :

```
$('.x').each(function() 
{
  setTimeout(function()
  {
    alert ($(this).attr('id'))
  },10000);
});
```

Obviously what happens is that the timeOut doesn't have reference to the original `$(this)`

Help ?

Comment: thanks Mark for the formatting

Answer (score 5):

`this` is context sensitive (and is different in `a_jQuery_object.each` than it is in `window.setTimeout`, but its reference can be copied to a different variable that is not context sensitive. It is conventional to use `that` for this purpose.

```
$('.x').each(function() {
    var that = this; 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        alert ($(that).attr('id'))
    },10000); 
});
```

Comment: Worked. I don't get why though. Surely the setTimeout is also outside the scope of the parent function so it would lose the var ?

Comment: The function was created in the same scope that `that` was created in, so it keeps access to those variables.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for your help. I missed the point that it was at the point where it was created rather than executed.